# How can I seamlessly and discretely communicate new URI launch parameters to a currently running application in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

**Case:** Click a URL in the browser and a video game that is currently running on user's desktop can ingest that data and do something.

I've been working on this for some time, but I don't know if I'm on the right path.

**What I currently have:**
A clickable URI in a webpage that can have different arguments for the client to recieve.
The URI scheme is registered in Windows. When clicking URI in the browser it will launch a c++ console 'launcher' or 'bridge' app that is already installed on the user's PC.
This 'launcher' is a middle-man that parses the URI arguments and communicates them to the main 'user' app (a video game) via IPC named pipes.

**How do I:**
In terms of UX, make the whole process discrete and seamless?

**Specifically, I need to:**
Keep launcher hidden from the user - no pop-up.
Needs to be only capable of running a single instance, even when invoked with new URI parameters. Do I just exit the current and create a new one?
User can click another URI in the webpage and the launcher will process the new arguments without displaying itself to the user.

**Tech constraints:**
Windows.
Preferably needs to be C++. C# could be a possibility.

**Existing example:**
Zoom conferencing software appears to works similar to this.
Clicking a URL in the browser launches a 'launcher' which starts the main app to video conference.
Closing that 'launcher' will minimize it into the system tray.
Clicking on a new link while the launcher is running does not start a new launcher, but it does start a new meeting.

How does something like this normally work?

Comment: you need an IPC mechanism (lie names pipe) between the launcher and the main app. SO that it can send requests to the app.

Comment: @pm100 thank you, but my question is mostly about hiding the launcher app from the user.

Comment: create a UI less launcher - its looks to see if the main app is running or not. If not then start it, if it is then IPC to it, then terminate the launcher. If you need the launcher all the time (why?) then create a ui less launcher for it . It can be the same binary just with different startup flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS automatically creates a console for /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE apps.  It doesn't automatically create a window for /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.  So use /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.

Then, create the named pipe *before* creating the main window.

1. If the return code tells you a new pipe was created (use `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE`), you're the primary instance, create main window and run normally, with an OVERLAPPED read on the named pipe to receive data from future invocations.
2. If instead you opened an existing named pipe, write your command line through the named pipe and exit without ever creating a window.

You don't need a separate launcher at all, and actually separating the launcher from the main application creates a race condition (a second launcher starts before the first instance managed to launch the main program / before the main program is up and running, doesn't see an existing named pipe, and thinks it is the primary copy).  You are better off putting both sides of the argument-forwarding logic into the main executable.

Comment: This would be very ideal. However, the game application is built in Unreal Engine. So far I have been unable to determine if this is possible without heavy engine modification.

Comment: The engine has nothing to do with it.  Except for receiving new values from a secondary launch, this is all done in early startup code.  If the engine provides `WinMain` you can do this in the constructor of a global variable (of class type which enables it to have a constructor), which the runtime will execute before executing `WinMain`.  Your argument-forwarder logic can call `GetCommandLineW()`, you don't need the `wszCommandLine` argument of `WinMain`

Comment: @Skate_and_Create: But if you're willing to live with the race condition, you can use a separate launcher.  As long as it is `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` not `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.  Same answer applies, just the primary instance action of "create main window" changes to "launch game".